# Is there a way to copy data from Sharepoint On Premise using Azure Datafactory or Azure Synapse Pipelines?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-pipeline

Hello and I hope you are well.

There is this Sharepoint On Premise that stores sa few tables I would like to analyse and transform. I would like to know if it's possible to connect Azure Datafactory or Azure Synapse Pipelines to Sharepoint On Premise in order to copy data to Azure?

I tried to go to linked services to see if there's connector for Sharepoint On Premises, but I only found something for Sharepoint Lists. So I was wondering how else to connect to this data source?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint lists? Have you considered the ADF/Synapse Pipeline OData connector?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odata?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties
Seems to support Windows Authentication. SharePoint Server supports OData access to Lists.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests

Answer (score 2):

Yes to copy data from Sharepoint On Premise using Azure Datafactory or Azure Synapse Pipelines. you will need the
**-Application ID
-Application key
-Tenant ID**

Open SharePoint Online site link e.g. `https://[your_site_url]/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx (replace the site URL).`

Use the image as reference.
[image]

The above url will allow you grant permission for your application ID.

•   App Domain: contoso.com
•   Redirect URL: https://www.contoso.com
•   Permission Request XML:
XMLCopy

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

[image]

Go to the Active driectory in the overview section you will get the **Tenant ID**
[image]

Go to app registrations and create a new app registration for **Clinet ID**
[image]

GO to the certificates and secrets for creating a secret value copy all the 3 into a note pad for the future use.
[image]
Go to the ADF or Synapse workspace
Create a Pipeline choose the web activity.
[image]

[image]
url as     `https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/tokens/Oauth/2`

Method: **POST**

Headers:
**Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
Body: grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[Client-ID]@[Tenant-ID]&client_secret=[Client-Secret]&resource=00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/[Tenant-Name].sharepoint.com@[Tenant-ID]
```

Replace the Client ID, Tenant ID, Tenant Name and Clinet Secret with your cofiguration

Next the Url to request the file:
The url looks something like this

https://[site-url]/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('[relative-path-to-file]')/$value
[image]
replace the site url and relative path to the file. the relative path should be the site again and the structre of folder path.

Now go back to the ADF or Synapse pipeline and create a new linked service for HTTP:
[image]
provide the name of the activity like sharepoint

Base url like `microsoft.sharepoint.com`

**Disable the certificate**

Authenication to **anonymous**

Create a Copy activity

Source:
in the source create a dataset it should be a HTTP type and format binary

choose the created linked service for the HTTP.

Relative url will be something like this.

```
/teams/sharepointaccess/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

In the sink additional header. add dynamic content and concatinate autraization token and output value from the web activity
Like shown in the picture.
[image]
[image]
Sink:

In the sink side create a dataset to the ADLS gen 2 in the Binary format
Attach the linked service for the sink
[image]
and you can trigger the Pipleline now.

[image]
Docs reffered:
You can also use the microsft documentation for your reference.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online